# Add SQL Server to existing Azure VM?

Tags: sql-server, azure, virtual-machine

I have a provisioned Azure VM which doesn't have SQL Server on it, as I did not select a VHD with the installation.

How can I add a SQL Server to that VM without creating a new one and migrating everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just download an edition of SQL Server from Microsoft and install it. Express edition is free.

Comment: But when you choose a vm plus sql server instance running those instances are only with express licence? I mean, if no, how to get a licence through azure to add SQL Server to my vm instance without obviously buying one licence outside?